# Jenkins - "Maven Repository Scheduled Cleanup Plugin" is deprecated how to replace it?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins deprecated plugin **[Maven Repository Scheduled Cleanup](https://plugins.jenkins.io/maven-repo-cleaner/)**

From [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/maven-repo-cleaner-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/mavenrepocleaner/RepositoryCleaner.java) it seems, that it is cleaning local maven repository based on the *"lastAccessTime"*.

What alternative solutions do I have?